# My Crontab doesn't work on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, cron, python, raspberry-pi

I have a python script in:

```
/home/pi/auto/wake_up.py
```

`crontab -e`:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/auto/wake_up.py >> /tmp/wake_up.log
```

log is created but with empty line
same when I put

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

on top of the python script

I checked the permissions they are right

Comment: Try capturing stderr to the log as well; append `2>&1` to the command. Also, what output does the script produce when you run it by hand?

Comment: Is the script executable (`chmod u+x /home/pi/auto/wake_up.py`)?

Comment: it also implies that `wake_up.py` outputs something to stdout

Comment: What's the output of "/usr/bin/python /home/pi/auto/wake_up.py" if you run it in the terminal?

Comment: First line of script and permission are not needed (if you run precede it with python). Add `print` statements on the script, to check where it break.

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer if you included a copy of your `wake_up.py` script.